# Why in the API rework was StoreName not specified in the table method of Kafka StreamsBuilder?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

In the Kafka StreamsBuilder the signature for table is only:

```
table(java.lang.String topic)
```

https://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/StreamsBuilder.html

Where as before you were able to provide a store name:

```
table(java.lang.String topic, java.lang.String queryableStoreName)
```

https://kafka.apache.org/0110/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/KStreamBuilder.html

Why was this removed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was not removed, but the API was reworked. Please read the upgrade notes for API changes: https://kafka.apache.org/11/documentation/streams/upgrade-guide

For this change in particular, the full details are documented via KIP-182: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-182%3A+Reduce+Streams+DSL+overloads+and+allow+easier+use+of+custom+storage+engines

You can specify the store name via `Materialized` parameter now:

```
table(String topic, Materialized materialized);
```

Comment: Thanks could not locate that KIP